# Are there any drinks which a person would make the blessing of HaAdamah?

Tags: blessing

Are there any drinks which upon consumption a person would make the blessing of boreh pri HaAdamah?

Comment: See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18333/170

Comment: Seee OC 205:2 .

Comment: Is a glass of unprocessed tomato-snot a drink?

Comment: מרק ירקות לפי הרא"ש בברכות, אף על פי שיש רק טעם. והלכה כמותו

Answer (score 4):

There is an opinion that if certain drinks are processed by heating/cooking they would warrant the brocha of ha'adama as through this process it extracts more of the original flavour.

The [Chayei Adam 52:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Chayei_Adam.52?lang=bi) explores this concept. He writes there:

> ### דין רוטב של פירות וירקות (סי' ר"ב)
>
> המבשל וירקות לאכילה מברך גם על הרוטב בפה"א דאע"ג דעל מי פירות כשסחטן מברך שהכל כדלעיל כלל מ"ט סי' ג' י"ל דיותר יוצא טעם הפירי ע"י בישול משיוצא ע"י הדריכה והסחיטה
>
> *One who cooks vegetables to eat, makes the 'ha'adama' blessing also on the sauce/juice since even though with the juice of the fruit when it is squeezed, one makes a 'she'hakol' as we stated earlier klal 49, se'if 3, there are those who say that there is more of a taste of the fruit when extracted through cooking, more so than squeezing...*

So at least according to this view, something like tomato juice, if it has been heated/cooked as part of its production would require the brocha of ha'adama.

This notion seems to be supported by Rav Tzvi Pesach Frank in Har Tzvi [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20947&st=&pgnum=103) (left column, second paragraph) who has a question on the production of cognac. As an aside, he looks at the Gemara in [Brachos 38a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.38a.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) that talks about date honey and how it is a brocha of 'she'hakol' as it retains no essence of the actual fruit but merely the moisture. However in the proceeding Gemara in [Brachos 39a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.39a.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) it talks about the water in which beets had been boiled and is regarded as having the same status as the beets themselves. He bring the [Tosfos](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.39a.11?lang=bi&p2=Tosafot_on_Berakhot.39a.11.1&lang2=bi) there where it writes:

> *"We recite on the beet soup בורא פרי האדמה even though the soup has in it only the juice of the beet and its taste; **one recites a b’rochoh upon the soup as he recites on the vegetable itself**. Even though we have learned earlier (38a) that fruit juice is merely sweat of the fruit and not fruit itself and we therefore recite שהכל נהיה בדברו, one can differentiate between the two."*

So once again, if a vegetable-based drink is heated as part of its production it retains the same brocha as the vegetable.

Comment: Also known as a creamed/puréed soup

Comment: Correct as far as the soup. But something like tomato juice which is sometimes cooked as part of its production would conceivably require a ha'adama. In mass production - one method is Hot Pulping which is done to extract the juice. See 21.4.3 and 21.4.3.1 here - http://ecoursesonline.iasri.res.in/mod/resource/view.php?id=147615

Comment: "Crushed tomatoes are boiled in their own juice in steam-jacketed stainless steel kettles or aluminium pans for 3-5 minutes to facilitate pulping. The crushed or chopped tomato pieces are heated to at least 82C for 15-20 seconds to inactivate pectic enzymes. On industrial scale heating is usually carried out in rotary coil tanks followed by passing through a plate heat exchanger and holding tube to achieve a processing temperature of 104C to retain at least 90% of the potential serum viscosity in the original fresh tomato...

Comment: This seems to address commercially-made products, but, I'm uncertain. I frequently cook vegetables to make a broth. Should I infer that the broth is *adama*? Does it matter if the broth is clear or it has vegetable pieces / pulp in it? Fresh-pressed carrot juice tends to have pulp / carrot bits, but if I cook carrots in water, it doesn't. Are both *adamah*, or is there a difference?

Comment: Hi @DanF - I'm no Rabbi but it would seem from the Chayei Adam that any heating of veg renders it ha'adama.

Answer (score 3):

As an update about this question:

Recently Rav Dov Lior published a shiur (available here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=veFtVA9dnh4) in which he says that fruits/vegetables which producers produce with intent of the production going at least partially for the making of juices (אדעתא דהכי), juice made from them, if there is no other things mixed on it, remain with it's original blessing. For example: carrot juice would require "HaAdamah".

He says that's Rashba opinion and the Chazon Ish pasken like it (12:09 in the video).

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/65111/the-blessing-over-drinking-fresh-orange-juice?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment180193_65115

Answer (score -3):

Disclaimer: This does not answer the question for HaAdamah blessing but only presents a related case in which this happens for haEtz blessing.

Rav Ben Tzion Aba Shaul writes in his shut [Ohr Letzion chelek 2 Perek 14 Piska 7](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=19979&st=&pgnum=137&hilite=) that if someone would squeeze the juice out of a grape directly into his mouth the beracha would be haEtz (just becomes haGafen when it gets to a container/cup). He writes on the notes that this is only true for grapes/wine, all other fruits even when squeezed directly into someone's mouth become shehakol.

Comment: I don't see how this is an answer. While one could extrapolate and implicit logical point, it remains unstated.

Comment: The Haeitz case was trivial since a glass of olive oil is Haeitz. You don't need chiddushim about grapes.

Comment: @DoubleAA Olive oil as a drink is debatable, as well as it's beracha. This was discussed in a question of yours https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12613/is-olive-oil-unhealthy.

Comment: @Julio no one debates that it's bracha is Haeitz. The discussion is just how to make it safe for consumption nowadays